# VB.net use numbers in textbox in array

Tags: arrays, vb.net-2010

this is for a school assignment.  I'm a brand newbie in VB.net (any programming, really) and this is my first assignment.

I have 5 text boxes in a form.  After numbers are entered, I want to perform a sq root, part of standard deviation on each number.  I am supposed to use an array.

I was able t use an array for lowest and highest (mostly from the book), but I don't know how to get the code to see the 5 items listed.

**Here's my code so far:**

```
Dim intGrade(4) As Integer
Dim intSquare As Integer
intGrade(0) = Val(txtGrade1.Text)
intGrade(1) = Val(txtGrade2.Text)
intGrade(2) = Val(txtGrade3.Text)
intGrade(3) = Val(txtGrade4.Text)
intGrade(4) = Val(txtGrade5.Text)
For intCount = intGrade To (intGrade.Length - 1)
   intSquare = CInt(intCount ^ 2)
   MsgBox(intSquare)
Next
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.